# OddEven Linked List code doesnt work on leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

There is a problem on leetcode called Odd Even Linked List.

It says:

Given a singly linked list, group all odd nodes together followed by the even nodes. Please note here we are talking about the node number and not the value in the nodes.

You should try to do it in place. The program should run in O(1) space complexity and O(nodes) time complexity.

Example:
Given 1->2->3->4->5->NULL,
return 1->3->5->2->4->NULL.

Here is my Node class

```
public class Node 
{
private int value;
private Node next;

public Node(int Value) 
{
    this.value = Value;
    this.next = null;
}

public Node()
{
    this.value = -1;
    this.next = null;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}public int getValue() {
    return value;
}public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

I got 8 items in list which has values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.  This is my output -->1-->3-->5-->7-->2-->4-->6-->8
And here is my Linked list method to solve OddEven task.

```
public void oddEven()
{
    if(head.getNext() == null)
        return;

    Node lastOdd = head.getNext(); // gets the value of last odd even in list.
    Node current = lastOdd.getNext(); // Puts the reference on the first even index.
    Node before = lastOdd; // This node, will always be one index before current Node
    int travel = 1, loop;


    while(current != null)
    {
        loop = travel;
        // Prvo petlja putuje do sledeceg neparnog elementa
        while(loop-- > 0)
        {
            before = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        if(current == null) // If it is end of the list, exit loop.
            break;

        before.setNext(current.getNext());
        current.setNext(lastOdd.getNext());
        lastOdd.setNext(current);
        lastOdd = current;
        current = before.getNext();

    }

}
```

It works perfectly fine on my pc. But when i put code in leetcode i get the error that it doesnt work. But it is same code. Here is code from leetcode

```
 /**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* public class ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode next;
*     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
* }
*/
  public class Solution {
   public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) 
{

    if(head.next == null)
        return head;

    ListNode lastOdd = head.next; // gets the value of last odd even in list.
    ListNode current = lastOdd.next; // Puts the reference on the first even index
    ListNode before = lastOdd;
    int travel = 1, loop;


    while(current != null)
    {
        loop = travel;
        // Prvo petlja putuje do sledeceg neparnog elementa
        while(loop-- > 0)
        {
            before = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if(current == null)
            break;



        before.next = current.next;
        current.next = lastOdd.next;
        lastOdd.next = current;
        lastOdd = current;
        current = before.next;

    }
    return head;
}
}
```

Here is the error i get

for input :[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Your answer :[1,2,4,6,8,3,5,7]

Expected answer :[1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]

But it is same method, where did i made mistake ?

Comment: `if(head.next == null) ` without checking `(head != null)` is erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the site and put your code in to make it easier to see whats going on, the issue is this line:

```
ListNode lastOdd = head.next; // gets the value of last odd even in list.
```

The first element of the list is 1, yet you are starting the last odd as being the next in the list, not the head of the list. Just changing that to:

```
ListNode lastOdd = head
```

and it provides the correct answer.

The code itself needs some tidy up, the inner while loop seems to serve no real purpose, not sure why thats there or its a left over element of a previous attempt?

Comment: It doesnt matter, my function is void. That return is the way to exit function, and their function is of type ListNode, so it returns empty head. It is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What `loop` and `travel` variables are doing? They are constant at 1 in each iteration, then why `while(loop-- > 0)` loop. Sorry didn't get what you are trying to achieve with that loop.

```
int travel = 1, loop;
    while(current != null)
    {
        loop = travel;
        // Prvo petlja putuje do sledeceg neparnog elementa
        while(loop-- > 0)
        {
```

Solution: Find the last node in the list. Move all even positioned nodes to the end, by doing append. Make sure you stop at the node marked as last in first step, else it would run into *infinite* loop.